# Hook after attachment added and cropped

Tags: plugin-development, images, attachments

I am looking for hook, that fires right after image uploaded, cropped for thumbnails and data posted to database.

I need it for image optimization **after**  uploading.

I tried *add_attachment* and it fires before image cropping and my code stuck. Help please!

Comment: How about `wp_handle_upload` it's a filter that fires after a file is being uploaded

Comment: This filter fires before image cropped and added to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is to filters needed for optimizing all images, that will be uploaded:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'random_function', 10, 2);
add_filter('image_make_intermediate_size', 'rand_function2', 10, 1);

function random_function($array, $string) {
// Some random action with main image
return $array
}

function rand_function2($file) {
// Some random action with cropped images
return $file
}
```